# OverFlow Button in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, html, css, sapui5

I am traying to create a big button that overflow an IconTabBar in SAPUI5.

I am working with IconTabBar, but I would like to use the empty space at the right of the IconTabFilter elements. Because I can not add additional buttons to the IconTabFilter, I want to add a button below the IconTabFilter and the using
css:
transform: sale(2.0);
transform-origin: 20% 40%;

and position the button over the empty space of the IconTabBar .

But as soon the element go outs of the container the next container hides the bottom.
I tried using overflow: visible, but still not working.

Does anyone know how can I make a big button that overflows another container?

[image]

Comment: Did you try modifying the z-index?

Comment: Reminder: CSS classes defined by UI5 standard controls are **not** part of the public APIs. It is very likely that your custom CSS will be broken in future UI5 releases. If you're e.g. creating an app for a customer without being able to control their SAPUI5 version upgrades, I'd strongly discourage from relying on custom CSS in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @BoghyonHoffmann, as long I work with a constant version of SAPUI5, I should not have problems with new releases, right?

Comment: @PabloSinder Since SAPUI5 versions are not indefinitely maintained, and in order to patch future vulnerabilities that are discovered, the SAPUI5 version in your app **has to be kept up-to-date** in accordance with the maintenance status: https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html. So you have to change the version at some point. But if you can't control it, avoid relying on custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I can discourage you from using (in its current form): define and implement an `IconTabButton` control. The basic idea is to trick the `IconTabBar` into accepting another type of control in `items` aggregation. However the `IconTabBar` only accepts controls that implement the interface `sap.m.IconTab` and its corresponding functions. The problem is, they are a lot.

We did develop a prototype by using [the source code on github](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/IconTabFilter.js), but gave up due to this needing a lot of work and maintenance (or at least more than we were willing to give).  One specific unresolved problem by this `IconTabButton` control is, when the tabs in the `IconTabBar` overflow, they use another rendering method that the custom control does not implement. So it may look good but only until it overflows. [Source code](https://pastebin.com/QxU5gL7z).

I am sharing this only for it to serve as an idea and eventual basis for proper implementation, I believe it is common use case to want some kind of a button inside the `sap.m.IconTabBar`. The control renderer must be migrated to V2, all the methods have to be properly adjusted.